# Dual-boot with Windows 10 on UEFI system and GPT partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, uefi, kubuntu

I built a new PC and want to dual-boot Windows 10 and Kubuntu. Currently i have installed Windows but when i try to install Kubuntu from bootable usb stick it stucks on Kubuntu logo with errors and i am not sure what i did wrong.

After i choose Start Kubuntu in grub at first it shows me [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ca2R.jpg):

```
MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
//...
systemd[1]: dev-loop0.device: Failed to set invocation ID for unit: File exists
systemd[1]: remote-fs.target: Failed to set invocation ID for unit: File exists
systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote File System
systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Failed to set invocation ID for unit: File exists
```

Then Kubuntu tries to start, it shows its logo and if i hit `f6` button i can see a lot of [similar errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irpxU.jpg):

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
See 'systemctl status sustemd-modules-load.service' for details.
```

It is not my first ubuntu installation but i have never encountered such problems on other machines. I used `Rufus 3.7 portable version` and performed usual process of creating bootable usb as always. I used `UEFI` and `GPT` parameters when creating usb in ISO mode (also had tried DD mode and it didn't work). Please look at pictures for more detailed error logs.

I did research this issue but seems like nothing i found managed to help me, i tried change grub settings and added `nomodeset` option and it didn't work, tried to create MBR partition on my usb, tried `Unetbootin` - these options also didn't work.

`Fast boot` option in Windows and `Secure boot` in my BIOS are disabled.
If it helps, here are my specs:

1. CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700x
2. GPU: Sapphire Pulse 5700xt
3. RAM: HyperX Predator ddr4 3200 2x8Gb
4. HDD: Seagate Barracuda 2 Tb
5. SSD: Samsung EVO 860 500 Gb - It is boot drive with Windows, a want to install Kubuntu here as well
6. MOBO: MSI b450-a pro

As bootable usb i used usb 3.0 stick by Kingston

Comment: Is your BIOS up to date?  For a Ryzen 3700, you still might need the latest kernel you can get.

Comment: @ubfan1 tried to install latest bios version, unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: @Nmath tried Etcher and also tried to flash usb with MBR setting in Rufus, also didn't work, i am still getting the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem is Kubuntu 19.04, i flashed Kubuntu 18.04 and it's working perfectly.